# z-index in IE9 not working as it should

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, z-index

Basically, i have an image inside a container with 2 navigation buttons. For some reason, the z-index in IE9 is not working as it's supposed to. All other browsers are displaying correctly.

In IE9 when i hover over the image, the image is on top. It's not suppose to. The navigation button should be on top so the user can click on the buttons.

I've read here about solutions, tried playing with the z-index, declaring all elements absolute with no success...

Is this a IE9 bug, and what's the fix/hack?

**EDIT:**

I've added a jsfiddle to explain it. If you hover over the image, the z-index doesn't work, just a you hover outside the image, the z-index works.

So far, i've cheated by adding a background color to modal-nav with 0 opacity. for some reason that works in IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/hkw9u7tL/13/ (works on al other browsers, except IE9)

HTML:

```
<div id="modal-overlay"></div>
<div class="modal m-photo"> 
    <div class="modal-close"></div>
    <div class="modal-nav prev"></div>
    <div class="modal-nav next"></div>
    <img src="../gallery/files/7/7/fc53534156328e43.32171077_l.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#modal-overlay {display: block; position: fixed; z-index: 9; left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);}

.modal {display: block; z-index: 99; position: absolute;}

.modal-close {position: absolute; z-index: 9999; right: -15px; top: -13px; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-image: url(../../images/icons2/close.png); cursor: pointer;}

/* modal navigation */
.modal-nav {position: absolute; z-index: 999; width: 35%; height: 100%; cursor: pointer;}
.modal-nav.prev {left: 0;}
.modal-nav.next {right: 0;}

/* MODAL specifics */
.modal.m-photo {width: 850px; height: 650px; background-color: #222;}
.m-photo img {position: absolute; z-index: 99; display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not an z index problem...? The close icon was wrong positioned outside the view... http://jsfiddle.net/hkw9u7tL/

```
.modal-close {position: absolute; z-index: 9999; right: 15px; top: 15px; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-image: url(../../images/icons2/close.png); background-color: #369; cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: no. the close icon is fine. looking at your jsfiddle, you kind of cheated. You added a background color to the navigation. Adding a background color works fine, but obviously i don't want color...

Comment: I made it on propouse to show the difference... i thought you were be able to change the background. But if you cant: http://jsfiddle.net/hkw9u7tL/11/

Comment: Give me the link to the live website so i will be able to help you :)

Comment: i can't it's on my dev. But i've edited my question with a new jsfiddle that explains it better...

Comment: As i've explained on my edit, the transparent background color works, but i don't like hacks. I was hoping for a clean solutiion.

Comment: I cant test on IE8 but if backgrounds solved, maybe an 100% transparent background can help too : http://jsfiddle.net/hkw9u7tL/18/